# How to configure modsecurity to log response which is greater than configured SecResponseBodyLimit?

Tags: mod-security

Modsecurity is a great tool to find data leakage issues in the response body. For my current project, I want to detect data leakage issues with a configured response body size set via `SecResponseBodyLimit` and the action for response body greater than this limit set to `ProcessPartial`.

This works as expected however, I would like to log response which is greater than the set limit. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ModSecurity sets a variable named `OUTBOUND_DATA_ERROR` to `1` whenever the response size is above the setting configured in `SecResponseBodyLimit`. Thus a simple rule that checks this variable can be used to achieve the requirement.
Example:

```
SecRule OUTBOUND_DATA_ERROR "@eq 1" "id:124,phase:4,t:none,log,msg:'DATA_OVERFLOW'"
```

[ModSecurity documentation reference](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual-(v2.x)#outbound_data_error)